# In Asynchronous n-step DQN, is there a global shared gradient vector or a gradient vector for each thread?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl

In this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.01783.pdf

This is the pseudocode for n-step DQN:
[image]

My question is: What does $\textrm{Initialize network gradients } d\theta \leftarrow 0$ mean? A global shared gradient vector or a gradient vector for each thread? I noticed that they use $\theta$ instead of $\theta'$ making me think it is a global shared gradient vector. But if this is the case, couldn't a thread clear the gradient vector while another thread is accumulating gradients?